# Haskell converting type Char to custom type Field

Tags: haskell, type-mismatch

I am trying to show several columns from a table using queries. But I get an error message with:

```
     * Couldn't match type `Char' with `[Char]'
  Expected type: [[[Field]]]
    Actual type: [[[Char]]]
* In the second argument of `mapMaybe', namely
    `(map transpose (table))'
  In the expression:
    mapMaybe (elemIndex columns) (map transpose (table))
  In an equation for `project':
      project columns table@(header : _)
        = mapMaybe (elemIndex columns) (map transpose (table))
```

My Haskell code is the following:

```
 project columns table@(header : _)
  = mapMaybe (elemIndex columns) (map transpose (table))
```

`table` is of type `Table`, which is `[Row]`, or `[[Field]]`. `Field` is a synonym of `String`.

Comment: Is `Field` a synonym of `String`?

Comment: Also, your error message doesn't match up with the provided code. Please double check the error that you're getting with this code.

Comment: The code you show doesn't match that in the compiler error message.

Comment: You should provide a minimal complete example which reproduces the error. We can't guess what's wrong otherwise.

Comment: Field is a synonym for String yes

Comment: I updated the error message as well

Comment: And what is `Table`?

Comment: Row is a list of fields. And table is a list of rows.

Comment: Can you write some simple examples how your function must run? For example, `project ... == ...`

Comment: It is run by executing main=
  printTable
    . project ["firstName", "lastName", "performance"]

Answer (score 2):

Lets start by looking through the signatures of the functions we're using:

`elemIndex` has the following signature:

```
elemIndex :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Maybe Int
```

`mapMaybe` has the following signature:

```
mapMaybe :: (a -> Maybe b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

Then we can specialize the type of `elemIndex` based on its argument, `columns` (which from the name I expect to be of type `[Field]`):

```
elemIndex :: [Field] -> [[Field]] -> Maybe Int
```

Thus:

```
elemIndex columns :: [[Field]] -> Maybe Int
```

Then let's do the same specialization to `mapMaybe` based on its first argument, `elemIndex columns`:

```
mapMaybe :: ([[Field]] -> Maybe Int) -> [[[Field]]] -> Int
```

Thus:

```
mapMaybe (elemIndex columns) :: [[[Field]]] -> Int
```

But I expect based on what you've said that `table` is a `Table`, which you have said is a `[Row]`, which is a `[[Field]]`, and cannot fill the role of the required `[[[Field]]]`.

So why did this happen? I think you're misusing `elemIndex`. `elemIndex` is a function that, given a value of type `a` and a list of type `[a]`, finds the index of the first occurrence of the value in the list and returns `Just` that value, or `Nothing` if it isn't there at all:

```
elemIndex 5 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
   > 4
```

However, it looks like you're trying to give it a value of type `a` and a list of lists of type `[[a]]` and get the index of the first sublist to start with the value:

```
elemIndex' 5 [[1, 5], [2, 4], [3, 3], [4, 2], [5, 1]]
    > 4
```

This function does not exist in the standard library (or any library I am aware of). I would suggest using a function `elemIndexBy`:

```
elemIndexBy :: (a -> Boolean) -> [a] -> Maybe Int
elemIndexBy fun list = go list 0
  where go [] _       = Nothing
        go (x:xs) ix
          | fun x     = Just ix
          | otherwise = go xs $ succ ix

elemIndexBy ((5 ==) . head) [[1, 5], [2, 4], [3, 3], [4, 2], [5, 1]]
    > 4
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Can you give an example on how to use elemIndexBy?

Comment: I've added a usage example.

Comment: interesting case for the automatic use of natural transformations on Monad Comprehensions, guided by the function's type. :) as in, skip the `listToMaybe` in the `listToMaybe [i | (x,i) <- zip xs [0..], fun x]`...